# Atom can't install any package on Ubuntu (Error code ELIFECYCLE)

Tags: npm, atom

Today, suddenly, Atom can't install any packages at all. It used to work fine earlier and I have a few packages installed already. But now it's failing with `Exit status 134`. This is happening no matter what package I try to install. I tried Hydrogen and Atom Beautify,

I tried both the GUI from Atom's settings as well as `apm install ...` (with and without sudo).

Here's the stack trace:

```
> core-js@2.6.11 postinstall /tmp/apm-install-dir-120129-5590-622axg.s39i7/node_modules/atom-beautify/node_modules/core-js
> node -e "try{require('./postinstall')}catch(e){}"


npm WARN deprecated graceful-fs@2.0.3: please upgrade to graceful-fs 4 for compatibility with current and future versions of Node.js
npm WARN deprecated minimatch@0.2.14: Please update to minimatch 3.0.2 or higher to avoid a RegExp DoS issue
npm WARN deprecated minimatch@0.3.0: Please update to minimatch 3.0.2 or higher to avoid a RegExp DoS issue
npm WARN deprecated core-js@2.6.11: core-js@<3 is no longer maintained and not recommended for usage due to the number of issues. Please, upgrade your dependencies to the actual version of core-js@3.
npm WARN deprecated circular-json@0.3.3: CircularJSON is in maintenance only, flatted is its successor.
npm WARN deprecated jscs-preset-wikimedia@1.0.1: No longer maintained. We recomment migrating to ESLint with eslint-config-wikimedia.
npm WARN deprecated nomnom@1.8.1: Package no longer supported. Contact support@npmjs.com for more info.
npm WARN deprecated coffee-script@1.12.7: CoffeeScript on NPM has moved to "coffeescript" (no hyphen)
npm WARN deprecated request@2.88.2: request has been deprecated, see https://github.com/request/request/issues/3142
Aborted (core dumped)
npm WARN enoent ENOENT: no such file or directory, open '/tmp/apm-install-dir-120129-5590-622axg.s39i7/package.json'
npm WARN apm-install-dir-120129-5590-622axg.s39i7 No description
npm WARN apm-install-dir-120129-5590-622axg.s39i7 No repository field.
npm WARN apm-install-dir-120129-5590-622axg.s39i7 No README data
npm WARN apm-install-dir-120129-5590-622axg.s39i7 No license field.

npm ERR! code ELIFECYCLE
npm ERR! errno 134
npm ERR! core-js@2.6.11 postinstall: `node -e "try{require('./postinstall')}catch(e){}"`
npm ERR! Exit status 134
npm ERR! 
npm ERR! Failed at the core-js@2.6.11 postinstall script.
npm ERR! This is probably not a problem with npm. There is likely additional logging output above.

npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in:
npm ERR!     /root/.atom/.apm/_logs/2020-02-29T09_58_40_245Z-debug.log
```

The last lines of the log file has the very same stack.

The one thing that I have my suspicion on is the fact that I installed `NodeJS` and `npm` recently for an Angular project. Could this be causing the issue?

I'm on Pop!_OS (`Ubuntu`) `19.10`, using `npm` `6.13.6`, and `Node` `v10.15.2`. 
Hitting `atom -v` gives me this (notice the difference between Node version from the one above): 
`Atom    : 1.43.0
Electron: 4.2.7
Chrome  : 69.0.3497.128
Node    : 10.11.0`

**Update:**
`apm install language-vue` worked but `apm install atom-beautify` and `apm install hydrogen` are still failing. No idea what's wrong here.

Any suggestion would be lovely. Thanks in advance. :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I had the same issue with atom-id-ui on Debian 10. I installed node.js 12 manually to fix it.

Try to add the repository and install node.js

```
# Using Ubuntu
curl -sL https://deb.nodesource.com/setup_12.x | sudo -E bash -
sudo apt-get install -y nodejs

# Using Debian, as root
curl -sL https://deb.nodesource.com/setup_12.x | bash -
apt-get install -y nodejs
```

Hope that could help you.

Greetings.

Comment: Your answer is missing a little detail - you need to tell us how you installed it. On Kubuntu 19.10 (eoan) the current version of nodejs apperas to be 10.15  (from `apt search nodejs`). To install would normally be `sudo apt install nodejs`; perhaps you used a private repo? There's nodejs 10.19 available for Ubuntu 20.04 (focal), see https://packages.ubuntu.com/search?keywords=nodejs&searchon=names&suite=all&section=all. Maybe you installed [manually or via snap](https://github.com/nodesource/distributions/blob/master/README.md) (v.12 and 13 can be had that way).

Comment: Have nuked the system a few times since the question. Installed node.js using the PPA on a fresh ElementaryOS (which is Ubuntu based) recently. No problem on Atom since then. Thanks.